# Working with function as a parameter to dictionary

Tags: function, dictionary, julia

I've to run an operation where columns from table have to be used to process function e.g. foo

```
> operateontable(operate on data a, (Dict{String,Function}("foo" => foo)))
```

where function definition of foo is

```
function foo(a;b=10)
 print("value of b",b)
end
```

example of call

> foo(; b=20)

how can I call foo function with a different value of b?

Comment: You do not show any actual call of foo in the code you post.  It would help if you could post a complete example of calling foo with one argument using the data and dictionary, and then it would probably be easy for someone to show how to extend that example's call to foo with one argument to a call to foo with two arguments, where one is a named argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not precise but perhaps you want to store functions with different default values in a `Dict`?

```
d = Dict{String, Function}("b5" => (a)->foo(a;b=5), "b7" => (a)->foo(a;b=7) )
```

This could be used as `d["b5"](10)`.